# XMPP Gtalk javascript

Tags: xmpp, google-talk

I want to create browser widget for gtalk.
I need to know about XMPP and its javascript support.
Can anyone guide me in this process.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Definitely check out [`Strophe`](http://code.stanziq.com/strophe/) and see an example implementation using that library at [`Speeqe`](http://speeqe.com/).

The author also has a very good book, [Professional XMPP Programming with JavaScript and jQuery](http://professionalxmpp.com/).

Answer (score 0):

A simple Google-search gives this:
http://xmpp.org/software/libraries.shtml#javascript

which results in

http://xmpp4js.sourceforge.net/
http://code.stanziq.com/strophe/

There might be some documentation for the respective projects.